# Novice regex issue determining if executable in os

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm having issues matching the "yes" string portion of this output (if the executable is not there i'd assume it says "no" but maybe there's a better cross-platform solution?):

```
checking for docker-compose... yes
```

Here's my code I wrote:

```
require 'mkmf'

logs = find_executable 'docker-compose'
if logs.match(/yes/)
  puts "hi"
else
  puts "bye"
end
```

It keeps saying "bye"

What am i doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. The *logs* variable doesn't contain what you think it does. `checking for docker-compose... yes` is printed to stdout, but not returned as a value or stored in *logs*. Instead, with the current code your variable just contains the path to the program if found, or nil, so the regexp will never match.
2. [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-match) returns a MatchData object. To return an explicit true/false value instead of relying on the truthiness of the MatchData object, replace it with the [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) method.

An alternative approach relies on using the truthiness of the [MakeMakefile#find_executable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-find_executable) expression directly. For example:

```
require 'mkmf'

p find_executable('docker-compose') ? 'found' : 'not found'
#=> "found"

p find_executable('no-such-file') ? 'found' : 'not found'
#=> "not found"
```

You can certainly use an if-then or case statement if you prefer, but the ternary operator offers a more concise way to express the semantics of your original post.